# Change the color of some items inside a databinded listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, silverlight-3.0, foreground

Inside my Windows Phone 7 application I have a list box with a list of 50 authors. 
I want to display the first 5 items of my list box with a white foreground (or black depending of theme), and the rest of them in gray.

```
<ListBox x:Name="AuthorsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1"    >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                  Name="{Binding Id}" Width="320" Height="70"
                                  TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                  Margin="0,0,0,10"  FontSize="30" 
                                  ManipulationCompleted="Author_ManipulationCompleted"/>                                 
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
AuthorsListBox.ItemsSource = AuthorsList.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `Foreground` property of the Textblock to the desired colour. Or to an indictor and use a converter to select the colour based on the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an "Onitemdatabound" to the listbox and then set the colour in that method

Comment: It looks like OnItemDataBound doesn't exist in Windows Phone ListBox. Eventually I created a converter and it works fine :)